# How to create regex to extract topic id from the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the form on my page with text `url` field. User can input there any value, like:

- http://example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=557761&sid=daea20300c8eea4681fd1d87aa76c622
- http://www.example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=557761&sid=daea20300c8eea4681fd1d87aa76c622
- www.example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=557761&z=123456
- example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=557761&sid=daea20300c8eea4681fd1d87aa76c622
- 557761

How can I validate that correct domain is given (`example.com`) and then extract topic id (`557761`)?

Looks like I should use `jQuery.isNumeric` first (to capture last case), if it is not numeric, then I can extract the value like `/^.*t=(\d+)$/`. But how should I check the domain in the regex?

Comment: Use `document.domain` to get "example.com" or whatever the page's value is.

Comment: And use the accepted answer from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values - to get the value for the "t" item in the querystring (topic id)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for all cases except the last case which you said you already have a solution for.

```
var pattern = "^(?:http(?:s)?://)?(?:www\.)?example\.com/forum/viewtopic\.php\?t=(\d+)";
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "i");
var match = regex.exec(string);
if (match) {
    alert(match[1]);
}
```

If you don't mind a less readable regex pattern then the following will work to capture all your cases (including the last one). Just replace the `pattern` line in the above code with the one below.

```
var pattern = "(?:(?:^(?:http(?:s)?://)?(?:www\.)?example\.com/forum/viewtopic\.php\?t=(\d+))|(^\d+$))";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
var domain = "example.com"
var regex = "http://(www)?"+domain+"/.+?t=([0-9]+)";
var match = regex.exec(inputString);
var topicId = match[1];
```

Comment: Hm, getting error - `TypeError: regex.exec is not a function`.

Comment: But works with `var regex = new RegExp(` and with `match[2]`.

Comment: @LA_, I am not very proficient with `javascript`. I wanted to give you a hint on how to build the `regex`.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the browser's URL parser using an `<a>` element:

```
var myhost = "example.com";

// Here url is the data given in the text input field
var hostname = $('<a>').prop('href', url).prop('hostname');
if (myhost == hostname) {
    alert('Host matched!');
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=example\.com/forum/viewtopic.php\?t=)\d+(?=\&)`

http://regexr.com?33333

This should work for you.

Comment: It shouldn't match `http://www.someotherexample.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=123123&asd` but it does.